# Excel VBA Page Breaks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook full of worksheets I'm trying to copy and paste the contents of into a word document. Right now the code loops through all the worksheets and pastes them into a word document, but on top of each other. I had to change `wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).Paste` to `wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False` and I'm not sure if this is the source of the problem; it does seem like a new page is being created, but the contents of the next worksheet just aren't being pasted into it. I'm not getting any error messages. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
Sub toWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fromWB As Variant
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim docName As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
wdDoc.Activate
'Creates InputBox that allows user to enter name to save document as
docName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Document Name", Title:="Save Word Document", Type:=2)
wdDoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=docName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument 'Saves document under user-provided name

fromWB = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", Title:="Open Merged Data")
If fromWB <> False Then
Set fromWB = Workbooks.Open(fromWB)
ElseIf fromWB = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
    GoTo ResetSettings
End If


For Each ws In fromWB.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdDoc.Range.Paste

    ws.Activate

    If ws.Range("A3").Value <> "" Then
    Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Resize(Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2).Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Copy
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdApp.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    wdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter


    wdDoc.Range.Collapse Direction:=0
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7
   End If
Next ws

wdDoc.Styles("Normal").NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
wdDoc.Save
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Set fromWB = Nothing
MsgBox "Imported into Word Document"


ResetSettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So the problem seems to be stemming from pasting twice from each worksheet. The code works when the stuff between `For Each` and `If ws.Range` is commented out. I changed the placement of the `If Statement` to right after `For Each` but that doesn't seem to have solved the problem either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I got to work:

```
Sub toWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fromWB As Variant
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim docName As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
wdDoc.Activate
'Creates InputBox that allows user to enter name to save document as
docName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Document Name", Title:="Save Word Document", Type:=2)
wdDoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=docName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument 'Saves document under user-provided name

fromWB = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", Title:="Open Merged Data")
If fromWB <> False Then
Set fromWB = Workbooks.Open(fromWB)
ElseIf fromWB = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
    GoTo ResetSettings
End If

For Each ws In fromWB.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).Paste

    ws.Activate
    If ws.Range("A4").Value <> "" Then
    Application.Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Cells.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2)).Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Copy
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdApp.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    wdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    wdApp.Selection.Collapse Direction:=0
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7
   Else
   wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7
   End If
Next ws

wdDoc.Styles("No Spacing").NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
wdDoc.Save
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
Set fromWB = Nothing
MsgBox "Imported into Word Document"


ResetSettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder edit while testing:

```
Sub asdf()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Const wdStory = 6
    Const wdMove = 0

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A7").Copy
        Set docApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        Set doc = docApp.Documents.Open("PATH OF FILE")
        docApp.Selection.EndKey wdStory
        docApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: There's a compile error for `objSelection.TypeParagraph()` @Chrismas007

Comment: `wdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        
        Const wdStory = 6
        Const wdMove = 0
        Set objSelection = wdApp.Selection
        objSelection.EndKey wdStory, wdMove` I took a look at the link but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? @Chrismas007